# Issue with changing how containers look based on values in an MD array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, socket.io

I am currently changing how certain containers work based on if a value is met in the array and if a value is then located in a container in real time using socket and a bit of Jquery.

It works fine for a single web page, but when I open up two instances of the same web page, its starts replicating containers if I refresh the page, when there is no duplicate values in the array.

In the image below I clicked refresh on the left instance but then another container appears on the right when there should be only two. A value will keep being added every time I refresh the left page, but when I then refresh the right page it then only has two and the left side has three.

[image: How it looks]

How the array looks:

```
[ [ 'User_488', null ],
  [ 'User_487', 'disable' ],
  [ 'User_477', 'disable' ],
  [ 'User_490', 'disable' ],
  [ '1000', 'enable', 'offline' ],
  [ '1001', 'enable', 'online' ],
  [ '1002', 'disable' ],
  [ '1004', 'disable' ]]
```

Code which changes how the containers look based on the above array, and seems to be the source of the issue:

```
socket.on("eventsCalls", function (calldata) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calldata.length; i++) {
        if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "Ringing") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("answer noanswer default").addClass("ring").attr('data-content', calldata[i][3]);
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "Hangup") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:not(.DND):contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("answer noanswer default").addClass("hangup").attr('data-content', calldata[i][3]);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("div[class*='tile']").removeClass("hangup");
            }, 3000);
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "ANSWER") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring noanswer default").addClass("answer").attr('data-content', calldata[i][3]);
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][2] === "NOANSWER") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring default").addClass("noanswer").attr('data-content', calldata[i][3]);
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][4] === "DND") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("hangup default").addClass("DND");
        } else if (calldata[i][0] && calldata[i][4] === "") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:contains('" + calldata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("DND default");
        }
    }
});

socket.on("eventsRegister", function (regisdata) {
    for (var i = 0; i < regisdata.length; i++) {
        if (regisdata[i][2] === "online") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:not(.answer .noanswer .ring .hangup):contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring default").css("background-color", "#78ff4d").html("<h6><img  src='../images/online.png'> <b>" + regisdata[i][0] + "</b></h6><p><span></span></p>");
        } else if (regisdata[i][2] === "offline") {
            $("div[class*='tile']:not(.answer .noanswer .ring .hangup):contains('" + regisdata[i][0] + "')").removeClass("ring").addClass("default").css("background-color", "white").html("<h6><img  src='../images/offline.png'> <b>" + regisdata[i][0] + "</b></h6><p><span></span></p>");
        }
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.default {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    background-color: white;
}
.hangup {
    background-color: LightSlateGray !important;
}
.hangup:after {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: url('../images/hangup.png') " + " attr(data-content);
}
.answer {
    background-color: orange !important;
}
.answer:after {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: url('../images/Incall.png') " +" attr(data-content);
}
.noanswer {
    background-color: #006666 !important;
}
.noanswer:after {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: url('../images/busy.png') " +" attr(data-content);
}
.ring {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
.ring:after {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: url('../images/ring.png') " +" attr(data-content);
}
.DND {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.DND img {
    display: none;
}
.DND h6:before {
    content: url('../images/dnd.png');
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening, am currently stumped.

EDIT: [JS Fiddle to emulate what is suppose to happen/ what its suppose to look like when there are multiple instances.](https://fiddle.jshell.net/37esjmjc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and it was very minor, I was removing everything with a class of default which was being removed every time a state changed, so now it will remove everything with class tile and prevent any duplicate containers.

```
socket.on("presenceusers", function (userPresence) {
    $('.tile').remove();\\ <------
    for (var i = 0; i < userPresence.length; i++) {
        if (userPresence[i][1] === "enable") {
            $presence.append('<div class="col-md-2 md tile default"><h6><img src="../images/offline.png"><b>' + userPresence[i][0] + '</b></h6></div>');
        }
    }
});
```